# Ant Regex Replace pattern with contents of file

Tags: javascript, html, regex, ant, build

I'm trying to figure out how to replace matching text in my files with contents of file.
Actually I want to inline javascript sources into HTML. But `loadfile` doesn't work in `replaceregexp`.

```
<replaceregexp flags="gs">
    <regexp pattern="\&lt;!--js--\&gt;(.*?)\&lt;!--/js--\&gt;"/>
    <substitution expression='\&lt;script src="min.js"\&gt;\&lt;/script\&gt;'/>
    <loadfile property="min.js" srcFile="compiled/min.js"/>
</replaceregexp>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of using `<replaceregexp>` to replace every `<!--js-->***<!--/js-->` with the contents of min.js.

```
<project name="ant-replaceregexp" default="run" basedir=".">
    <target name="run">
        <property name="js.pattern"
            ><![CDATA[[<]!--js--[>](.*?)[<]!--/js--[>]]]></property>

        <loadfile property="min.js" srcFile="compiled/min.js"/>

        <replaceregexp file="test.html" flags="gs">
            <regexp pattern="${js.pattern}"/>
            <substitution expression="${min.js}"/>
        </replaceregexp>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! My config got cleaner :) Can I ask you one more thing, how to wrap everything I've got from file into `<script></script>` Or even better leave <--js--> marks (that is what I tried to do in initial post) and insert <scprit></script> between them (so that I can run several times)?

Comment: You're welcome! To wrap everything, create a new property after `<loadfile>`: `<property name="min.js.wrapped"><![CDATA[<script>${min.js}</script>]]></property>`. Use this property in your `<substitution>` expression.